# the slave postgresql is not working

Tags: postgresql

I have set up the master(192.168.1.10) and slave(192.168.1.11) postgresql. I got the error when login to the slave postgresql:

```
postgres@sonia-System-Product-Name:~$ psql
psql: FATAL:  the database system is starting up
```

Transferring data by using:

```
psql -c "select pg_start_backup('initial_backup');"
rsync -cva --inplace --exclude=*pg_xlog* /data/dbs 192.168.1.11:/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/
psql -c "select pg_stop_backup();"
```

the postgresql.conf is

```
listen_addresses = 'localhost,192.168.1.10'
wal_level = 'hot_standby'
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'cd .'
max_wal_senders = 3
hot_standby = on
```

I do not know why I can not login to slave postgresql. There is not problems with SSH connection.I have tried to restart service, but it did not work. please someone can help me out.

Comment: Please describe how you configured the standby. What is in `recovery.conf`? Also, what does the PostgreSQL log on the standby say?

Comment: the recovery.conf is   cat recovery.conf
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'host=192.168.1.10 port=5432 user=rep password=pass'        
trigger_file = '/tmp/postgresql.trigger.5432'  .   the postgresql.conf is hot_standby = on

Comment: Look at the PostgreSQL server log file, it should tell you what is going on.

Comment: I  removed pg_xlog from the slave server and then used pg_start_backup() again. I tried to fix the issue, but I got the another error: sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart: database system was shut down in recovery,  required WAL directory "pg_xlog" does not exist. how do I fix this? thanks

Comment: solved the problems. removed slave pg and recreated slave database. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem sloved and share the solution. Thanks.

```
   master server= 192.168.1.10
   slave server = 192.168.1.20
```

Setup Master and slave postgresql
configuring Master server

```
ssh-keygen 
ssh-copy-id the slave-ip-address
vi  /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf
listen_addresses = '*'
wal_level = hot_standby
max_wal_senders = 3
```

create replication role:

```
CREATE USER repuser WITH REPLICATION PASSWORD 'password';
```

configure the ip address on the master in order to the slave can have access to the master :
 vi /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf

```
#rep
host    replication     repuser   192.168.1.20/24       md5
hostssl replication     repuser   192.168.1.20/24       md5
```

configure the ip address on the slave server:
vi /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf

```
host     replication     repuser   192.168.1.10/24    md5
```

stop posgresql service on master server ( it is very import to do this step, otherwise, you will get log error on the slave sever when run psql.

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql stop
```

configuring the slave server
vi /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses = '*'
hot_standby = on
```

stop service and clean up data on Slave server

```
#/etc/init.d/postgresql stop
#cd /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/
#rm -rf *
```

Create recovery file
vi /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/recovery.conf

```
primary_conninfo = 'host=192.168.1.10 port=5432 user=repuser password=password'
standby_mode = on
```

copy data from the master to the slave database

```
rsync -av /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/* 192.168.1.20:/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/
```

start service on both slave and master

```
slave:~# /etc/init.d/postgresql start
master:~# /etc/init.d/postgresql start
```

verify the state of replication and run the following the command on the master sever

```
psql -x -c "select * from pg_stat_replication;"
```